# mapping variables in vim with regex

Tags: vim

Is this possible to map `{some_variable_name}=` to `{some_variable_name} =` in `vim`? where `{some_variable_name}` is `[A-Za-z0-9]`?

From some other hints, I was trying:

```
:inoremap ?P<name>([A-Za-z0-9-_])=  ${name} =
```

***Edit*** so that, if I type "a=", it will be converted to "a = ", and if I type "blah=", it will converted to "blah = "

which is not working.

Kindly help.

**EDIT**: Possibly a easier way of definning the problem: replace "=" to " = " dynamically, when followed by [A-z0-9].

I am trying, but not yet succeeded. Kindly help

Comment: make an example, explain what do you want. I cannot understand your requirement.

Comment: @Kent: example/intention added

Comment: so you want something like `%s/\v(\S)\=/\1 =/g|%s/\v\=(\S)/= \1/g` ?

Comment: @Kent: yes seems so. But not sure how to map it

Comment: %s/\v(\S)\=/\1 = /gc is also doing, but not in map

Comment: just map = ,add space b4 and after. your sub line will add extra spaceto x=(space) y

Comment: :imap  %s/\v([A-z0-9-_])\=/ \1 = ?

Comment: @Kent: that will not work, as that will put space on all=, like != and ==; which I sont want

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This insert mode mapping does what I *think* you want but your question is a real mess so… well:

```
:inoremap <expr> = getline(".")[col(".") - 2] !~# "[a-zA-Z]" ? "= " : " = "
```

But typing `<Space>=` is a *much* better solution IMO.

Edit:

Due to some "weirdness" in the way Vim handles cursor position in insert mode, `getline(".")[col(".") - 2] !~# "[a-zA-Z]"` unintuitively compares the character just before the cursor with the regular expression `[a-zA-Z]`. Use `getline(".")[col(".") - 1]` for the character that comes after the cursor.

Comment: while your solution(as always) working perfectly (as I have already marked as accepted), I am still to understand what has happened. specially, `[col(".") - 2] !~#` as I understand, you are going 2 columns back from the current column of current line ....then...clueless. Can you kindly explain?